# How to make an android phone ring programatically AS IF it was receiving a call?

Tags: java, android

First off, I'm a beginner in mobile development.
I've seen many similar questions but none of them would answer specifically this.

I'm developing a game for android, platform target `2.2`, in `Java` (eclipse, android sdk, avd, etc), and would like to know if there's a way to make the phone ring (based on the current ringtone, settings, etc) **as if you were receiving a call from your app.**

Think of it as if **one of the characters of the game would be calling you**, to notify you about something (for example, you could let something in a game kind of 'oven', and your assistant would call you when the food is ready)

Is it possible?

Comment: This sounds like something you shouldn't be allowed to do!

Comment: maybe this link helps you. I'm not an andorid developer, but I think this class do what you want. [RingtoneManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html)

Comment: @Sean P: There are plenty of apps in the Marketplace that cause your phone to ring programmatically (e.g. to get you out of an awkward situation haha).  This doesn't seem much different =)

Comment: Will look into this RingtoneManager, but I can't seem to find any code samples to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO this is not possible. If you want to do that you have to create an `Activity` with a layout similar to that of the incoming-call-screen.
Sure you can use the Android code as it is open source:  [Layout Directory on GIT](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Phone.git;a=blob;f=res/layout/call_card.xml;h=ae0dbf259add52b37e007c18bb0f18a7142f77f6;hb=HEAD)

Answer (score 1):

I know you can get the curremtly selected ringtone from the preferences:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/RingtonePreference.html

and then you should have a look at music players
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

and play your ringtone and of course creating that custom Activity Martin is talking about